# H1 tag gets copied along with text when contenteditable is set to true in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

Contenteditable is set to true on a `h1` tag. Now when I copy the content and paste it in the same area then even the `h1` tag gets copied. This behavior is only in firefox.
**firefox version:** 26.0
for example:

```
<H1 contenteditable="true">
    This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this text.
</H1>
```

Now when I copy it from Firefox browser and paste it in same area. Then it adds one more h1 tag instead of just the text inside the tag.

Now if I replace the above code with div or p it works perfectly even in Firefox. problem is only with heading tags.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this text.
</div>
```

or

```
<p contenteditable="true">
    This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this text.
</p>
```

Both `div` and `p` work fine. But I need it with heading tags.

look the js fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/LVXsD/

Please help me solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: same here...no problem at all,works fine!!! :)

Comment: did you copy the text and paste it in the contenteditable area ??

Comment: check the screen shot above

Comment: do the same thing in chrome guys..it will copy only the text and when we paste it. it will go inside the h1 tag instead of creating one more h1 tag . understand my question

Comment: doesnot suit my requirement

Comment: same code above with div,p tags works perfectly..The only problem is heading tags in firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, I'd say div is the safest bet across the board. Any element you wish to truly edit (be it a span, header, etc), you can place inside the div and edit as if it were just that element.

Similarly i faced the same situation where i tried so many things to get the correct solution in Firefox. In all other browser(chrome, IE7+) the copy paste functionality give the plain text only.

So for resolving this issue in Firefox i used some javascript line of code as follows

```
  $('[contenteditable]').on('paste', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain') ||     
 prompt('Paste something..');
 document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
```

});

please follow the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/Ee3yC/89/